# Why would average execution time increase when vertically scaling async ruby jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

The setup: Ruby 2.2.5 running on Heroku, sidekiq 4.1.1 for processing asynchronous jobs. MongoDB + mongoid on the backend, so no ActiveRecord.

We have been having memory issues on Heroku, so we increased the dyno size to a PX dyno, which increases the memory and CPU speed. Instead of seeing the job execution time (given to us by New Relic) stay the same or decrease, as expected, we found that it went up noticeably, over 2x in some cases. I can't imagine why this would be the case - how does more resources equal more time to execute the same work?

Comment: You really need to ask the Heroku guys. They've responded well to my trouble tickets in the past, and my project is quite small.